# Rsync bottlenecks

Tags: rsync, nfs

Are there options to diagnose rsync bottlenecks, in particular to figure out the read time, transfer time, write time and possibly compression time and other overheads ?
In my current case, it's going slow via NFS but I'm curious as to general diagnosing methods.

Comment: If you can avoid using `rsync` with an NFS filesystem, but instead connect to an `rsync` server directly on the remote system (`ssh`/`rsync` or `rsyncd`), you'll find it works far more efficiently.

Comment: Well, here there's no remote per se, both drives are nfs mounted on a local system. Playing with NFS options doesn't seem to change much, hence the search for the bottleneck. One's a very large enterprise SAN, the other a large drive managed by some VM.

Comment: `rsync` is probably not the way to go if your source and destination are both NFS filesystems.

Comment: What could be a better solution? cp won't cut it  ;-)

Comment: `rsync` will work, but it really isn't very efficient across NFS. Definitely enable `--archive` (`-a`). Try enabling  `--whole-file` (`-W`) and don't bother attempting compression (`-z`), but that's probably already the way it's running.